# Parameter Not Being Passed to R via rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm having some trouble with rpy2 and the R library "e1071". I'm trying to retrieve probability data from an SVM prediction, but it is never included in the returned object.

Building a model calling "svm" with "probability=TRUE" will tell the model to include extra data when requesting prediction. Prediction data is returned through the "predict" command with a "probability=TRUE" parameter and should return a complex data structure with labels and a "probabilities" attribute. My issue is the probabilities attribute is not included in the results. Its like the probability parameter is never included in the predict call.

Here is some example code (e1071 R library must be installed):

```
import numpy
import rpy2
import rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri
rpy2.robjects.numpy2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
importr('e1071')


# configure the data set
SAMPLES = 50
trainingDataClassless = numpy.random.random((SAMPLES, 7))
trainingDataClasses = numpy.where(numpy.random.random((SAMPLES, 1)) > 0.5, 0.0, 1.0)
trainingDataFactorClasses = rpy2.robjects.FactorVector(trainingDataClasses)

# create the args for the svm
svmargs = {"x": trainingDataClassless, "y": trainingDataFactorClasses, "probability": True,
           "kernel": "linear", "type": "C-classification"}

print("Starting SVM with parameters: %s" % (svmargs,))
svmObj = rpy2.robjects.r['svm'](**svmargs)

print("SVM Analysis")
predictOutcomes = rpy2.robjects.r['predict'](svmObj, trainingDataClassless, probability=True)
print("outcomes: %s" % (predictOutcomes,))
probs = rpy2.robjects.r['attr'](predictOutcomes, "probabilities")
print("probs: %s" % (probs,)) # should NOT be NULL!
```

More info on the predict function in R (with a working probability example) can be found on the [e1071 documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/e1071.pdf) on page 39.

Comment: Just encoutered this.  I would have been miserably stuck for hours had this question and it's response not been posted.  Thanks @lgautier for being on top of this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute appears lost somewhere, presumably during conversion between low-level and high-level representation of the resulting R object (a factor).

Using the low-level interface call is a workaround (see below), but it would be really nice if you could report the issue on the rpy2 issue tracker on bitbucket.

```
r_predict = rpy2.robjects.rinterface.globalenv.get('predict')
r_traindata = rpy2.robjects.Matrix(trainingDataClassless)
r_true = rpy2.robjects.BoolVector([True])
predictOutcomes = r_predict(svmObj,
                            r_traindata,
                            probability=r_true)
```

**edit:** an issue was opened... and closed (the bug is fixed - https://bitbucket.org/rpy2/rpy2/issues/299)

Answer (score 0):

Your R functions (`svm` and `predict`) need to run on the R side of things and not on Python as Python does not see or know those specialized functions. Python can just serve for the numpy samples calculations, as conduit to call functions, and for printing results:

```
# PASS PYTHON DATASET OBJECTS INTO R  
# numpy objects => R matrices 
tdClassless_row,tdClassess_col = trainingDataClassless.shape
rmatrix_tdClassless = rpy2.robjects.r.matrix(tdClassless, 
                            nrow=tdClassless_row, ncol=tdClassless_col)
rpy2.robjects.r.assign("tdClassless", rmatrix_tdClassless)

tdFactorClasses_row,tdFactorClasses_col = trainingDataFactorClasses.shape
rmatrx_tdFactorClasses = rpy2.robjects.r.matrix(tdFactorClasses, 
                            nrow=tdFactorClasses_row, ncol=tdFactorClasses_col)
rpy2.robjects.r.assign("tdFactorClasses", rmatrix_tdFactorClassless)

# OBTAIN THE SVM FUNCTION
rsvm_funct = rpy2.robjects.globalenv['svm']

# PASS SVM PARAMETERS
svmObj_py = rsvm_funct (
     rpy2.robjects('x = tdClassless'), 
     rpy2.robjects('y = tdFactorClasses'),
     rpy2.robjects('probability = TRUE'),
     rpy2.robjects('kernel = "linear"'), 
     rpy2.robjects('type = "C-classification"')
)
# ASSIGN svmObj in R 
rpy2.robjects.r.assign("svmObj", svmObj_py)

# OBTAIN THE PREDICT FUNCTION
rpredict_funct = rpy2.robjects.globalenv['predict']

// PASS PREDICT PARAMETERS
predictOutcomes = rpredict_funct(
     rpy2.robjects('svmObj'), 
     rpy2.robjects('tdClassless'), 
     rpy2.robjects('probability = TRUE')
)
```